# How to animate multiple objects one by one after some intervals android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

How to animate multiple objects  one by one after some intervals android
i am using this code for animation

```
 for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                Toast.makeText(ProjectFirstActivity.this, y + "",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myimageview[y],
                        "translationY", 0, -200);
                oa.setDuration(1000);
                oa.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

but it is animating all in one go but i want one by one animation of my imageview please help

Comment: Assuming you have four image views.. add them in a switch case with values from 1 to 4. Now update the values from 1 to 4. once you reach 4, reset to 1.

Answer (score 8):

No need to use Threads and Handlers. Instead of that use,

`objectAnimator.setStartDelay(delay);`

Using that you can stop that animation for the respective 'delay'

Try this code..

```
  int delay = 1000;
  for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {                         
      Toast.makeText(ProjectFirstActivity.this, y + "",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myimageview[y],
                    "translationY", 0, -200);
      oa.setDuration(1000);
      oa.setStartDelay(delay);
      oa.start();
      delay = delay+1000;
   }
```

Comment: I tried this, and the time delay works perfectly, but the views stay put.... no movement at all. I've got exactly the same code :(

Comment: no worries! I was using the wrong array! (noob) Oh, @Noaman Akram, using for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) is a less good way to do a for loop. Rather use for(int y = 0; y < myimageview.length; y++) That way you know you'll only run the for as many times as the number of views in your array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loop to generate `AnimatorSet` and then play them sequentially using `set.playSequentially(yourAnimatorSetListHere);`

I haven't used list in below mentioned snippet.

```
  AnimatorSet decSet = new AnimatorSet();
            decSet.playTogether(
                    ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(mTextSlidetoCancel, "visibility", View.GONE, View.VISIBLE),
                    ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(mBtnMicActive, "visibility", View.GONE, View.VISIBLE),
                    ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(mChronometer, "visibility", View.GONE, View.VISIBLE));
           decSet.setDuration(125);


            AnimatorSet decSet2 = new AnimatorSet();
            decSet2.playTogether(
                    ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(mBtnAttach, "visibility", View.VISIBLE, View.GONE),
                    ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(mBtnEmoji, "visibility", View.VISIBLE, View.GONE),
                    ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(mEditTExt, "visibility", View.VISIBLE, View.GONE)
                    );
            decSet2.setDuration(125);

            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set.playSequentially(decSet2,decSet);
            set.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

*Try out this way!*

```
public Integer[] Imgid = {R.drawable.anim2, R.drawable.anim3,
            R.drawable.anim4, R.drawable.anim5}; // your image array.
    Animation anim;
    Handler handler;
    ImageView iv;
    int count;
    Runnable galleryAnimRunnable;
```

*Inside onCreate*

```
iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagetype);
handler = new Handler();

   galleryAnimRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        if(count==Imgid.length){
            //do any action
        }
        else{
            anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationScreen.this, R.anim.fade_out); // load your desire animation.
            iv.setBackgroundResource(Imgid[count]);
            iv.setAnimation(anim);
            count++;
            handler.postDelayed(galleryAnimRunnable, 300); //set your desire delay time.
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sleep` call isn't helping because when one posted UI job goes to sleep, then next one starts and goes to sleep immediately following that, and so on.  Then the first job wakes up and runs, followed closely by the second job awakening and running, etc.

If you want the `sleep` to help you need to wait before posting each job, which could be as simple as something like the following:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(ProjectFirstActivity.this, y + "",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ObjectAnimator oa = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myimageview[y],
                    "translationY", 0, -200);
            oa.setDuration(1000);
            oa.start();
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT:  Although the above explains why you were having problems, I would recommend going with something like the answer posted by Jgdsh Seerm using `setStartDelay()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way!

```
ImageView image1;
public int currentimageindex1=0;
Timer timer;
TimerTask task;

private Animation animation1;
private Animation animation2;

int img[] = {R.drawable.aa, R.drawable.bb, 
        R.drawable.cc,R.drawable.dd,R.drawable.ee,R.drawable.ff,R.drawable.gg,
        R.drawable.hh};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    // Create runnable for posting
    final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            AnimateandSlideShow();

        }
    };

    int delay = 1000; // delay for 1 sec.

    int period = 4000; // repeat every 4 sec.

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {

         mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);

    }

    }, delay, period);



}

public void onClick(View v) {

    finish();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
  }

/**
 * Helper method to start the animation on the splash screen
 */
private void AnimateandSlideShow() {

    image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);


    image1.setImageResource(img[currentimageindex1%img.length]);
    currentimageindex1++;


}
```